# searching a file for a line and starting a second search from there

Tags: python, file, search

I have a file with a bunch of albums and the list of songs of each album after it. Names of albums start with `#` and names of songs start with `*`. I'm trying to make a script that will give me all the songs in a specific album but it keeps printing all the songs in the entire file. Here is the code I wrote

```
def song_list(album):
    albumDB = open('Pink_Floyd_DB.txt','r')
    song_list = []
    i = 0
    lines = albumDB.readlines()    
    for line in lines:
        if album in line:
            for song_name in lines:
                if '*' in song_name:
                    song = song_name.split('::', 1)[0]
                    song_list.insert(i,song)
                    i += 1
    for song in song_list:
        print(song)
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your dataset?

Comment: Tangentially, you forgot to `albumDB.close()`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `<key, values>` dictionary in which the keys are the album names and the values the list of corresponding songs `dict_song: <albums, songs>`.

```
dict_album = {}
with open(r'album.txt') as text:
    album = ''
    song = ''
    for line in text:
        #line = line.rstrip("\n")
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith('#'):
            album = line.replace("#", "", 1).strip() # remove only first occurency 
            dict_album[album] = []
        elif line.startswith('*'):
            song = line.replace("*", "", 1).strip() # remove only first occurency 
            dict_album[album].append(song)
        else:
            # should never occur
            continue
```

To access the dictionary you only need to access it directly by key, or by using the `.get()` function, which takes as its first parameter the key (album name) and optionally you can put as a second parameter a value that will be returned when the key is not found in the dictionary (eg. "Album not found")

```
query_album = "The Wall"
print(dict_album.get("The Wall", "Album not found"))
```

and you get the list of songs:

```
['Another Brick in the Wall Pt 1', 
 'Comfortably Numb', 
 'Vera']
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code explicitly loops over all the lines, and prints all of the songs from all albums each time it sees a matching album (with double newlines, because `print` adds one of its own).  You are also reinventing `list.append()` for no good reason.

If I'm guessing correctly that your file looks something like

```
# The Wall
* Another Brick in the Wall Pt 1
* Comfortably Numb
* Vera
# Wish You Were Here
* Shine On You Crazy Diamond
* Wish You Were Here
```

then you will simply want to read up to the next `#` line.

```
with open(file) as songs:
    found = False
    for line in songs:
        line = line.rstrip("\n")
        if line == "# " + album:
            found = True
            continue
        if line.startswith("#"):
            if found:
                break
        if line.startswith("*") and found:
            print(line.lstrip("* "))
```

A better approach for a more complex program would be to open and parse the file just once, then manipulate the resulting structure in memory. But then, a better solution still is to ditch this ad-hoc format, and save your database in a standard machine-readable format like JSON or YAML.  Here's a simple YAML stucture of the data above:

```
---
The Wall:
- Another Brick in the Wall Pt 1
- Comfortably Numb
- Vera
Wish You Were Here:
- Shine On You Crazy Diamond
- Wish You Were Here
```

and you'd read it with

```
import yaml

with open(yamlfile) as data:
    albums = yaml.safe_load(data)
```

Now, `albums["The Wall"]` returns the list of songs from that album.